# Couldn't read row 6, col 6 from CursorWindow. (ANDROID)

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Buenas

Estoy intentando rellenar un array bidimensional, con datos de mi DB SQLite. Pero sucede lo siguiente:

Es mi primera vez con SQLite por cierto, y andaba averiguando si existia algo como un "Result Set" o un "Data Table"... y encontre el llamado "Cursor". Ok, empeze a usarlo... insertando una sola fila en cada tabla (todo normal) pero ahora cuando inserto otra fila mas en mi tabla materias, la aplicacion se crashea al momento de intentar navegar en el cursor.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 6, col 6
>   from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly
>   before accessing data from it.

Mi tabla no tiene 6 filas.... solo tiene 2. Este es mi codigo por cierto:

```
 public String[][] getMaterias(){
    String[][] materias = new String[rows][cols];
    Cursor cursor = admin.selectLog(DBScheme.Tabla_Materias);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    for(int f = 0; f < rows; f++){
        for(int c = 0; c < 6; c++){
            materias[f][c] = cursor.getString(cursor.getPosition());
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return materias;
}
```

Mi tabla esta conformada por 6 columnas. Estuve observando como se maneja el cursor y por lo que pude ver:

- **cursor.getCount()** y **DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries()** solo devuelven el numero de **celdas**.
- Los metodos **moveToFirst(),moveToNext()...** se manejan por las celdas igualmente, mas no por las filas.

(Corrijanme si mi entendimiento esta errado...)

En fin, Cursor lo asocio asi como un **ArrayList**... por decirlo asi. Por el tema de sacar las filas igual no hay problemas, simplemente divides el número de celdas entre el número de columnas y ya esta.

Pero lo que me tiene en duda es como se navegaria en una tabla que contiene mas de una fila? pense que con esa funcion bastaria.

**ACTUALIZACION**

Experimente ahora con un ciclo while a ver como se comportaba y para mi sorpresa, solamente se esta capturando los valores de **la primera fila**.

```
public String[][] getMaterias(){
    String[][] materias = new String[rows][6];
    Cursor cursor = admin.selectLog(DBScheme.Tabla_Materias);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    try {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),cursor.getString(cursor.getPosition()).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return materias;
}
```

Como se le diria al cursor que siga con la siguiente fila?? :S

Answer (score 0):

Me siento como un tonto ahora mismo, porque la solucion estaba en mis ojos todo este tiempo... jajajajaja! Solo tenia que cambiar esto:

```
materias[f][c] = cursor.getString(cursor.getPosition());
```

por esto:

```
materias[f][c] = cursor.getString(c);
```

Torpezas de novato, sin duda alguna.